# Is "We all know running has health benefits" correct English?

Tags: grammar

"We all know running has health benefits" isn't how I would write the sentence (I'd probably say "We all know that running offers many health benefits"), but is it formally incorrect?  I want to say that you really need the "that" after "we all know," but I'm not sure.

Comment: [on hold] the word *that* can be omitted where it introduces a subordinate clause, as in your case.

Comment: ...though it's not always advisable: _We all assumed sitting positions were acceptable._

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use "that" here and then also the sentence would be formally correct. Both ways, the sentence is correct..